# runtime error window , how to debug in release mode in VS c++ 2008

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2008, release, runtime-error

i have have application that i compile in visual studio 2008 ,
but i also have installed 
VS 2010 and 2005 ,   when i compile my app in release mode and run it outside the compiler i 
getting after few seconds window massage that i don't know from which part in my app is coming . when i press on the debug window its opening the 2010
2 questions:

1.how i make it open in VS 2008 ? ( i already set in regedit to use 2008 as default)
2.how do i catch from where this error window is coming from in my app?
is there any extra settings i can set in VS 2008 to give me more info when i run 
it in release mode?

[image: debug window error]

Comment: does it die in debug? basically run it in debug from vs2008 - alternatively turn on debug in release mode and "debug" the release version in 2008...

Comment: how do i turn on the debug in release mode ?

Answer (score 2):

Turn on debug in release mode.

select `Release configuration` for the project so that you are creating the correct version, then on the project that crashes right click and select properties.

[image]

You will see something similar to this (but this is vs2005)

[image]

Choose the circled options and change the value to be Program Database.

Now select Linker in the properties list:

[image]

And change the generate debugging info to `yes`

You may need to change the C++ property for optimisation to off as well because the debugging may not be quite as straightforward with it on. This is because of the various ways the code is organised after comilation to maximise speed etc. (but that is left as an exercise to the reader. )

Comment: Thanks to run it from visual studio ? in release ?
or as stand alone app?

Comment: So long as it says release (as per my first screenshot) just press f5 - although if there are command line params/working directory - you can set them on the same properties dialog  - Debugging (top level) just above the C++ entry.

Comment: ok thanks , im going to try now , do you mybe have idea about the first question ?

Comment: @user63898 you mean why it invokes 2010 rather than 2008? it is probably a windows/vs2010 set up thing - I'm not sure I know tbh.

Comment: ok i setup like you told me, and now it dosn't crash ? any idea why?
can i leave it that way ?

Comment: It could be a lot of things, ideas: 1) are you sure you were running a debug build before by accident? It might have triggered an assert which slips through in release. 2) did you turn off optimisation? if yes it can stop errors triggering in small applications - but it's dangerous to leave it - turn optimisation back on - does it trigger the crash. 3) sometimes we all make mistakes and possibly the release app you last built was an intermediate version with a bug you fixed - the new release build is the corrected one. (I'm clutching at straws without code)

Comment: can be , now the error the run time is back , and when i run it in the IDE im getting another error ... i hate this ...

Comment: You'll need to show your code I think - try to take the code you have and create a smaller app that exhibits the behaviour - look at http://sscce.org/ I think this question has run its course.

Comment: hu man its 5000 lines of code and i have no idea from where the error comes